# Why the functions such as "_write" in retarget.c is not linked when retarget.o is archived in a static library?

Tags: c, linker, arm, uart, newlib

I implement a retarget.c to retarget the printf output to serial port for debugging, it can be linked and works very well, if my link command likes this:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -fno-builtin -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=main.map -T"$(LINKERFILE)" -o main.elf main.o retarget.o $(BUILDDIR)/libs.a -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group`

but when I archive `retarget.o` into the archive file `$(BUILDDIR)/libs.a`, and the link command likes this one:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -fno-builtin -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=main.map -T"$(LINKERFILE)" -o main.elf main.o $(BUILDDIR)/libs.a -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group`

it can be linked successfully, but the function printf doesn't output anything to the serial port, it seems that the my own version functions, such as `_write` in the retarget.c are not used in the final compiled program.

Comment: What is `$(LIBSFILE)`? I guess you must convert your compiled code to a static lib or dynamic lib to do what you want to do.

Comment: Try linking your static library before or after libc and see if that changes things. I don't remember the rules for which objects and symbols get picked, but the order of the command line arguments to gcc (which you seem to be using) definitely matters.

Comment: @LPs @Art Thank you for your replies, I updated my questions and replaced some macros with actual arguments. @Art, later on I removed `-Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group` in the command line, then the link command like this: `arm-none-eabi-gcc  --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -fno-builtin -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-map=main.map -T"$(LINKERFILE)" -o main.elf  main.o $(BUILDDIR)/libs.a`, but the result still the same, the function printf doesn't output anything to the serial port

Comment: Did you try to link your lib with -l option?

Comment: @LPs, yes, anyway, I believe the `nosys.specs` forced another library was linked firstly. I believe I found the answer somewhere else, here is the link: 
https://sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2006/msg00036.html

Answer (score 4):

your `_write` implementation isn't linked because `_write` is **already defined** in `libnosys.a` which you included via `--specs=nosys.specs`.

To use the `_write` symbol defined in your static library `libs.a`, invoke gcc with `-Wl,--undefined=_write` during the final linking.

see: `man ld | grep -A4 --undefined=symbol`

```
--undefined=symbol
    Force symbol to be entered in the output file as an undefined symbol.
```

### Details

First: [spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html). `gcc` is a compiler-driver which invokes subprograms including `cc` and `ld`. Spec files are used to specify the behavior of `gcc`.

The compiler's builtin specs can be seen with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -dumpspecs`. Try it out!  See also: [`gcc -dumpspecs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html)

Passing `--specs=nosys.specs` at the beginning of the command line inserts a `-lnosys` in the call to `ld`. ([What are “nosys”, “nano”, “rdimon” terms when using ARM GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453293/what-are-nosys-nano-rdimon-terms-when-using-arm-gcc))

`arm-none-eabi-objdump -t arm-none-eabi/lib/libnosys.a | grep _write` locates the `_write(...)` that is likely overriding the one you defined in `$(BUILDDIR)/libs.a`

See also: the Makani firmware repository, in which a static library implementing syscalls [marks them as `--undefined`](https://github.com/google/makani/blob/master/avionics/firmware/util/BUILD#L19) (Generation of [linker options](https://github.com/google/makani/blob/master/lib/bazel/c_rules.bzl#L81))