Linker problem while retargeting newlib with static library
I use a Gnu Arm toolchain with GCC v12.3.
I want to do some retargeting on my stm32. For this, I have a file stdlib_override.cpp:
#include <cerrno>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
    
extern "C" {
    
    int _gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, void *) { return 18; }
    
    int _getpid(void) { return 1; }
    
    int _write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) { return 0; }
    
    int _read(int /*fd*/, const void *buf, size_t count) { return 0; }
    
    int _kill(int, int)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    
    int _close(int) { return -1; }
    
    int _fstat(int, struct stat *st)
    {
        st->st_mode = S_IFCHR;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int _isatty(int) { return 1; }
    
    int _lseek(int, int, int) { return 0; }
    
    int _open(char *, int, ...)
    {
        /* Pretend like we always fail */
        return -1;
    }
    
    int _wait(int *)
    {
        errno = ECHILD;
        return -1;
    }
    
    int _unlink(char *)
    {
        errno = ENOENT;
        return -1;
    }
    
    int _times(struct tms *) { return -1; }
}

My main.cpp is:

#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
    timeval tv{};
    std::printf("Hello, World!\n");
    std::printf("%d\n", gettimeofday(&tv, nullptr));
    return 0;
}

I use CMake as a build system. My CMakeLists.txt is :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(gettimeofday)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_link_options(
        -mthumb
        -specs=nosys.specs
        -specs=nano.specs
        -Wl,-Map=output.map
        -Wl,--print-memory-usage
        -Wl,--gc-sections
)

add_library(arm STATIC stdlib_override.cpp)

add_executable(gettimeofday main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(gettimeofday PRIVATE arm)

My toolchain file is :
# define main characteristics of the target
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ARM)

set(TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_LOCATION "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/12.3 rel1")
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX arm-none-eabi-)

# the path to where toolchain relative includes, libs or bin may be found
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_LOCATION}")

set(TOOLCHAIN_COMPLETE "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT_LOCATION}/bin/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_COMPLETE}gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_COMPLETE}g++.exe)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_COMPLETE}objcopy.exe CACHE INTERNAL "objcopy tool")
set(CMAKE_SIZE_UTIL ${TOOLCHAIN_COMPLETE}size.exe CACHE INTERNAL "size tool")

# CMake will try to compile using the predefined compiler. STATIC_LIBRARY arg is always needed when cross compiling
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# find_program() should never try to find any programs in CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# find_library() should only try to find any library in CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
# find_file() or find_path() should only try to find any file in CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

But the linker seems unable to find functions in stdlib_override.cpp:
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0xc): warning: _close is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0xe): warning: _fstat is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x2): warning: _getpid is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-gettimeofdayr.o): in function `_gettimeofday_r':
gettimeofdayr.c:(.text._gettimeofday_r+0xe): warning: _gettimeofday is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): warning: _isatty is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-signalr.o): in function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0xe): warning: _kill is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x10): warning: _lseek is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x10): warning: _read is not implemented and will always fail
C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/PROGRA~2/GNUARM~1/13/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/thumb/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): warning: _write is not implemented and will always fail

Full linker command is :
C:\PROGRA~2\ARMGNU~1\125863~1.3RE\bin\AR10B2~1.EXE -g -mthumb -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--print-memory-usage -Wl,--gc-sections CMakeFiles/gettimeofday.dir/main.cpp.obj -o gettimeofday  libarm.a

It finds them if I don't use a static libray (using add_executable(gettimeofday main.cpp stdlib_override.cpp)).
I think there is an order problem between newlib and my lib, but how can I control that?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

"I think there is an order problem between newlib and my lib" - Link order matters. You need to provide the linker first with the objects requiring symbols and then subsequently with the libraries/objects providing those symbols.

Can you build with cmake --build build --verbose or equivalently add set(VERBOSE 1) so we see the full linker invocation?

Okay, I'm guessing this has to do with sections too. Add the contents of output.map and objdump output for all object files and libraries involved.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68264279/857620 answers my question.
